# No module named pages.urls

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Django Gerbi-CMS and getting no luck. I've got through the installation a couple of times and not getting anywhere. When I run the server I get the error:

`No module named pages.urls`

When I install it tells me that it's installed correctly. However I look in the python2.7/site-packages and pages is not in there.

I installed on an existing site a while ago and I can't see what different other than pages and the other depencencies not showing in the above directory.

The last command I ran to install the package was:

```
$ sudo pip install django-page-cms
```

which like I said installed but nothing showing up in my site-packages.

Link to site - http://packages.python.org/django-page-cms/installation.html

SETTINGS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    #'authority',
    'pages',
    'south',
    'blog',
)
```

URLs:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    # Trick for Django to support static files (security hole: only for Dev environement! remove this on Prod!!!)
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^admin_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
 urlpatterns += patterns('',      
(r'^', include('pages.urls')),
)
```

If you need any other info please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you included the downloaded application on INSTALLED_APPS declaration....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the installtion process several times I worked out that because I was using 'sudo' it was installing on the server and not inside the virtualenv!

So when you install the app you need to Install it without sudo, otherwise it will install outside of the virtualenv!

Answer (score 0):

Did you included the application in your settings.py file in the section called

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'mptt',
    'tagging',
    'pages',      # You have to include it here      
)
```

Comment: I commented out but when I added it back in I can't even run 'python manage.py runserver' as i get this error - 

Error: No module named pages

Comment: @Josh: Did you added all the necessary details on the settings.py

Comment: Yes, i've got through it all and included it all in the settings.py file. However like i mentioned above when i go into my site-packages it doesn't even seem to be installing it. Yet about 10 minutes before I managed to install PIL no problems.

Comment: did you ran the python manage.py sycdb command after the installation

Comment: Yeah, after i run syncdb I get this error -     raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError pages: No module named pages

Comment: please go to the code on github and have a look on the example folder. Match your urls.py and settings.py and try it once.

Comment: I've matched my code from an exisiting project. It seems like it's not installing correctly. Surly it would show up in my site-packages folder if it's installed? Or am I wrong?